# array index and address return same value

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  int a[3] = {1,2,3};
  printf("\n\t %u %u %u \t\n",a,&a,&a+1);
  return 0;
}
```

Now i don't get why a and &a return the same value, what is the reasoning and the practical application behind it? Also what is the type of &a and could i also do &(&a) ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Now i don't get why a and &a return the same value, what is the reasoning

`a` is the name of the array that decays to pointer to the first element of the array.
`&a` is nothing but the address of the array itself, although `a` and `&a` print the same value their types are different.

> Also what is the type of &a?

Pointer to an array containing three `int`s , i.e `int (*)[3]`

> could i also do &(&a) ?

No, address of operator requires its operand to be an lvalue. An array name is a non-modifiable lvalue so `&a` is legal but `&(&a)` is not.

Printing type of `&a`(**C++ Only**)

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int a[]={1,2,3};
   std::cout<< typeid(&a).name();
}
```

**P.S:**

Use `%p` format specifier for printing address(using incorrect format specifier in `printf` invokes Undefined Behavior)

Comment: but i don't get how &a is int (*)[3], i mean it is not that we declared it anywhere to be of this type.

Comment: Yeah, but why would i use c++ to tell me the type if i am working on C. Isn't there any other reason why the type is int (*)[3]? Or is it something that just makes sense, thinking about it logically?

Comment: @n0nChun : For an array of n elements of type `T`, the address of the first element has type `‘pointer to T’`; the address of the whole array has type `‘pointer to array of n elements of type T’`.

Comment: Thanks. And i found this too : )
http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter5/arrays_and_address_of.html

Comment: @n0nChun: If you say `int i;` you did not declare `i` as a pointer to `int`, yet `&i` is a pointer to int ;)

Comment: i have to ask one more thing.
if you say int a[3]={1,3,4};
int *p;
p = &a;

isn't there a type mismatch because p is int* and &a is int (*)[3].
But it goes down well with the compilers.

Comment: @Prasoon:I disagree that a and &a are both the same thing.a is the base address of that array while &a means the address of the base address.Suppose if base address is ff01 then &a will give the address where the content is ff01.